# Recording username with meteror autoform

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm creating a form using cfs:autoform to capture a photo and caption from submitted on the client like this:

```
Photos = new Mongo.Collection("photos");
Photos.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  userId:{
    type: String,
    autoValue:function(){return this.userId},

  },
  userName:{
      type: String,
      autoValue:function(){return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}).username},
  },

  groupMembers: {
    type: String
  },
  comments: {
    type: String  
  },
  fileId: {
    type: String
  }
}));
```

I've gotten the code to successfully capture and fill in the userId, as well as the comment and uploaded photo, but I can't seem to get it to capture the username.

Comment: Shouldn't ```{_id: this.userId}).username}``` and ```userName``` match like for ```userId``` above?

Comment: isn't one the name in the Photos schema (and can therefore be anything) and the other the username in the users collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely because you're using `find` instead of `findOne`. Since `find` returns a cursor and not a single document you can't access the `username` value, because it's not a property of the cursor. If you change it to `findOne` it should work.

```
userName:{
      type: String,
      autoValue:function(){return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).username},
  }
```